# github-action set env from date printed on stdout

Tags: github-actions

I use github actions.
I have this cmd line who print "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT" inside the shell:
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -f M3/build/publications/kotlinMultiplatform/pom-default.xml -DforceStdout

I want to put this data into env.BUILD_VERSION

I've try

```
 run: |
   echo "::set-env name=BUILD_VERSION::$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -f M3/build/publications/kotlinMultiplatform/pom-default.xml -DforceStdout)"
```

but it don't work

can you help-me?

Comment: What does it do?  Is there an error?  What does your build output look like?

Comment: What is the output of `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -f M3/build/publications/kotlinMultiplatform/pom-default.xml -DforceStdout` command? What OS do you use (`runs-on`)? Also, try to exclude maven command into separate line, like `export MVN_RESULT=$(mvn help....)` and then use this variable inside `echo`.